# Can't receive response from servlet in Jsp file

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am trying to send some query from jsp file to servlet via post method and then get some modified result from servlet to jsp file.

I am able to complete first part successfully, but I cannot receive the response in jsp file.

Servlet post method is:-

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    JSONObject js = <some method to get json>;
            System.out.println(js); //works fine
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(js.toJSONString());
}
```

And my jsp code is:

```
    <script>
    function getData() {
        $.post("MyServlet", {
            query : "Wolf of wall street",
            choice : "M"
        }, function(response) {
            alert("hello" + response);
        });
    }
   </script>
```

The output is:

[image]

How can i get that json string ?

Comment: you are certainly getting the json object from your servlet, it would be easier to access its property like: response.someProperty, try printing it on the browser console like: console.log(response) ,still if you want only string, you can try updating this line: response.setContentType("plain/text");

Comment: @Arvind this looks like an answer

Comment: also I would suggest to add this as the last line of the method: response.getWriter().close();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting json as response need to stringify it.

```
 <script>
    function getData() {
        $.post("MyServlet", {
            query : "Wolf of wall street",
            choice : "M"
        }, function(response) {
            alert("hello" + JSON.stringify(response));
        });
    }
   </script>
```